# Fedora boot hangs when second disk is attached

Tags: fedora, disk, reboot, hang

I am running

```
# uname -a
Linux UlanBator 5.16.11-200.fc35.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Feb 23 17:08:49 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

#
```

and I have these disks

```
# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: ST9500423AS     
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x1015d719

Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048   2099199   2097152     1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       2099200 976773119 974673920 464.8G 8e Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-root: 50 GiB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-swap: 7.91 GiB, 8493465600 bytes, 16588800 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/zram0: 7.74 GiB, 8313110528 bytes, 2029568 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-home: 406.85 GiB, 436849344512 bytes, 853221376 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/sdb: 1.82 TiB, 2000398933504 bytes, 3907029167 sectors
Disk model: OneTouch HDD    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x011b8246

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1             2048 1953514583 1953512536 931.5G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb2       1953515520 3907029166 1953513647 931.5G 83 Linux

#
```

sdb is an external drive connected via usb-3.

```
# blkid -o list
device                   fs_type      label        mount point  UUID
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/dev/mapper/fedora-swap  swap                      [SWAP]       6b92c40e-8f23-4360-90a9-fba7670ebeeb
/dev/mapper/fedora-home  ext4                      /home        2124d813-f982-4d49-b2d7-a26522ce254a
/dev/mapper/fedora-root  ext4                      /            65a51d0a-4132-4af0-8170-94be6c67deef
/dev/sda2                LVM2_member               (in use)     MM7jJv-ar5b-KC6l-bez8-9cPQ-CJmJ-6KAwxW
/dev/sda1                ext4                      /boot        981faec7-1770-4f29-96aa-30e7fc479e59
/dev/zram0               swap         zram0        [SWAP]       dc6e7c08-ef58-4118-9716-dbb41ba94129
/dev/sdb2                ext4         partition-2  /mnt/sg/2    9ee90eaf-d345-4d75-a2e4-fe1439fa8f12
/dev/sdb1                ext4         partition-1  /mnt/sg/1    ed902376-506e-4ff9-98f0-b32f796d43a6

# grep -v ^# /etc/fstab
/dev/mapper/fedora-root                   /               ext4  defaults        1 1
UUID=981faec7-1770-4f29-96aa-30e7fc479e59 /boot           ext4  defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/fedora-home                   /home           ext4  defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/fedora-swap                   swap            swap  defaults        0 0
UUID=ed902376-506e-4ff9-98f0-b32f796d43a6 /mnt/sg/1       ext4  rw,relatime,seclabel,noauto        1 2
UUID=9ee90eaf-d345-4d75-a2e4-fe1439fa8f12 /mnt/sg/2       ext4  rw,relatime,seclabel,noauto        1 2
angkorwat:/mnt/lc/a/media                 /mnt/media      nfs   rw,noatime,nfsvers=3,rsize=32768,wsize=32768 0 0
angkorwat:/mnt/lc/a/projects              /mnt/projects   nfs   rw,noatime,nfsvers=3,rsize=32768,wsize=32768 0 0
angkorwat:/mnt/lc/b/java                  /mnt/java       nfs   rw,noatime,nfsvers=3,rsize=32768,wsize=32768 0 0

#
```

The problem I'm having is reboots hang whenever the external drive is attached to the system, even if the sg mounts are commented out in fstab.  The only possibilities I can think of is sdb having a dos label type, which almost certainly isn't the problem because sda also has one, and sdb using primary partitions 1 and 2, which is unlikely to be the problem because neither is marked as bootable.

Comment: When the system hangs at boot, how far in the boot process it has got? Has it gone past the GRUB menu? If it's displaying the Fedora boot splash screen, press Esc to see boot messages instead - those might give you more information about what the system is trying to do. Also, check your BIOS boot order settings: the boot flag in the partition table only has meaning for the standard Windows MBR code. If it has been replaced by something else (e.g. an old installation of GRUB?) on the external disk, that might be causing the hang.

Comment: You might want to disable filesystem checks in `/etc/fstab` for your external drive

Answer (score -3):

That means your computer is trying to boot from the second disk. Don't insert the drive until the logon screen is shown.

Comment: That is highly unlikely and not a real solution to the problem. I've flagged your answer as low quality.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).